# Conditional Login in the beforeAll - Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

Looking for a repeatable pattern for putting conditional logic in the beforeAll statement for a Protractor spec. This is what I've got so far:

```
beforeAll(function () {

login.devTestLogin();

//Check to see if depedent service is up. If its down, log
customerManagement.resultCount.isPresent().then(function (result) {
    if (result) {
        console.log("Dependent Service - up");
        customerManagement.clickManageCustomer(0);
    } else {
        console.log('Dependent Service - down');
        process.exit(0);
    }
  });
});
```

This is the error message that I keep getting:

```
[13:25:10] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
>> 
Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 100 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Process finished with exit code 100
```

Does anyone have a good repeatable pattern for executing test/don't test logic?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use beforeAll(). You wrap your it() calls in if statements.

```
describe('App', () => {

    customerManagement.resultCount.isPresent().then((present: boolean) => {
      if(present) {
          it('should do some stuff', () => {
            browser.get('/whatever')
              // add some more thenes here
              .then(result => expect(result).toContain('Some stuff'));
          });
      }
    });
});
```